# Data validation in mvc not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I am now on a mvc project, I have trouble on the validation of user input. Below are the steps I used to perform the validation:

1. My entity looks like below:

   ```
   public class Sysuser
   {
   public Guid User_id { get; set; }  //pk
   public Guid? Permission_id { get; set; }
   public Guid? Sex_id { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessage="Pls input the user name")]
   [StringLength(50,ErrorMessage="UserName must less than 50 chars")]
   public string User_name { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pls input the pwd")]
   public string Password { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
   public string Phone { get; set; }
   public string Userdesc { get; set; }
   public bool Isfamer { get; set; }

   public string Ctrlpwd { get; set; }  
   public Guid Parent_id { get; set; } 

   public Syspermission Permission { get; set; }
   public Bassex Sex { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. in the SysUser.aspx page, I included the js file that required:

   ```
   <script src="../../Scripts/validation/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">  </script>
   <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```
3. in the SysUser.aspx page, I put the html elements in the BeginForm like below:

   ```
   <td style="width:100px;  text-align:right;">用户姓名：</td>
   <td><%=Html.TextBox("User_name", (b == null) ? string.Empty : b.User_name, new { @class = "textbox" })%>
   <%=Html.ValidationMessage("User_name")%>
   </td>
   ```
4. in the web.config, I included below attributes :

   ```
   <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
   <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
   ```

In order to test the functionality, I leave the User_name textbox blank, When I hit the submit button, but it throw me an exception like below:

```
  public global::System.String user_name
    {
        get
        {
            return _user_name;
        }
        set
        {
            Onuser_nameChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("user_name");
            _user_name = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
            ReportPropertyChanged("user_name");
            Onuser_nameChanged();
        }
    }
    Exception Thrown at : _user_name = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);　This property can't be set to null.
```

why I get this error? anyone can help me to work it out? thx.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a stronly-typed view (of `SysUser.aspx`), and then use instead of:

```
<%=Html.TextBox(...)
```

this function:

```
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User_Name, ...)
```

The `TextBoxFor` function will automatically create unobtrusive validation properties in the `<input>` element. So can find some more information here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/10/asp-net-mvc-2-strongly-typed-html-helpers.aspx

And by the way, you should always validate the model server-side as well:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MySaveFunction(MyModel model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    // save entity in db and redirect to for example success page
  }
  return View(model); // show the form page again
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, But I have thousands of textbox in <%=Html.TextBox(...) style. I can't modify it one by one.

Comment: I'm afraid it's the only way to go. A strongly-typed view makes validation both client and server side a lot easier. And Visual Studio can generate a form including all elements for you (select the Edit template when creating a new view).

Comment: that's sad to me. Do you have other methods to do client side validation?

Comment: Yes there is, you need to implement all the client-side validation rules manually, see: http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/ But when you make changes in your model, don't forget to apply these changes for the validation rules as well.